# How to avoid floating point format error

Tags: c++

I am facing with following issue. 
when I multiply two numbers depending from values of this numbers I get different results. I tried to experiment with types but didn't get expected result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>    
int main()
{
    const double value1_39 = 1.39;
    const long long m_100000 = 100000;
    const long long m_10000 = 10000;
    const double m_10000double = 10000;

    const long long longLongResult_1 = value1_39 * m_100000;
    const double doubleResult_1 = value1_39 * m_100000;

    const long long longLongResult_2 = value1_39 * m_10000;
    const double doubleResult_2 = value1_39 * m_10000;

    const long long longLongResult_3 = value1_39 * m_10000double;
    const double doubleResult_3 = value1_39 * m_10000double;

   std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << value1_39 << '\n';
   std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << longLongResult_1 << '\n';
   std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << doubleResult_1 << '\n';
   std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << longLongResult_2 << '\n';
   std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << doubleResult_2 << '\n';
   std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << longLongResult_3 << '\n';
   std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << doubleResult_3 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

result seen in debuger

```
Variable            Value
value1_39           1.3899999999999999
m_100000            100000
m_10000             10000
m_10000double       10000

longLongResult_1    139000
doubleResult_1      139000

longLongResult_2    13899
doubleResult_2      13899.999999999998

longLongResult_3    13899
doubleResult_3      13899.999999999998
```

result seen in cout

```
1.39                                                                                                                                    
139000                                                                                                                                  
139000                                                                                                                                  
13899                                                                                                                                   
13900                                                                                                                                   
13899                                                                                                                                   
13900
```

I know that the problem is that the problem is in nature of keeping floating point format in computer. It keeps data as a fractions in base 2.
My question is how to get **1.39** * **10 000** as **13900**?(because I am getting **139000** when multipling with **100000** the same value) is there any trick which can help to achieve my goal?

I have some ideas in my mind bunt not sure are they good enough.

1) pars string to get number from left of . and rigth of doth

2) multiply number by 100 and divide by 100 when calculation is done, but each of this solutions has their drawback. I am wondering is there any nice trick for this.

Comment: No there is not - but you can round the number to a number of significance places

Comment: @EdHeal can you please provide more details how to do that?

Comment: This is an output problem. Set how many places you want to display and you'll get nice, rounded values. In the debugger you should expect ugly, raw values to be shown.

Comment: Perhaps read up about `cout` and `setprecision`. The debugger will display the true value that the computer understands. If you want a less precise value that read up `cout` and `setprecision`

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision

Comment: setprecision will not solve my issue I will get 13899 in output and not 13900

Comment: `setprecision` will not help if you are viewing numbers in a debugger. If precision is an absolute must you may have to operate in integers and use [fixed point math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).

Comment: I am not viewing in debugger I am doing cout, and it prints 13899.

Comment: There's no code with `cout` in your example, though.

Comment: @tadman just added, not added originally becouse Cout will not solve probleme as after multiplication I am having different number.

Comment: That helps clarify considerably. Remember that floating point math can be a bit imprecise, that's just how it is, so if you need absolute precision you need to use a fixed-point system internally. With 64-bit values you can get a *lot* of precision.

Comment: @tadman can you please provide more details what you mean saying 'fixed-point system internally' and `64-bit values`

Comment: If you need, for example, 10 places of precision, you use integer values that are all multiplied by ten billion. Since 64-bit values are in the range of +/- 9.2e18 then you can get +/- 9.2 billion with ten places of precision, or in other words, more than you get with a 32-bit integer value that has no precision.

Comment: What we see from the output is `double` numbers are rounding as one would expect when printed, but the `long` numbers aren't. The `long` numbers are already damaged here: `const long long longLongResult_3 = value1_39 * m_10000double;` This makes no attempt at rounding, it truncates (just lops off the fractional portion). `const long long longLongResult_3 = std::llround(value1_39 * m_10000double);` may do what you want, depending on what it is you really want. I do not believe you can get a get a compile time  constant out of it `llround`.

Comment: Docs on C++ rounding functions: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments already said, no there is no solution. This problem is due to the nature of floating points being stored as base 2 (as you already said). The type floating point is defined in [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754_revision). Everything that is not a base two number can't be stored precisely in base 2.

To be more specific

**You CAN store:**

- 1.25 (2^0 + 2^-2)
- 0.75 (2^-1 + 2^-2)

because there is an exact representation.

**You CAN'T store:**

- 1.1
- 1.4

because this will result in an irrational fracture in the base 2 system. You can try to round or use a sort of arbitrary precision float point library (but even they have their limits [memory/speed]) with a much greater precision than float and then backcast to float after multiplication.

There are also a lot of other related problems when it comes to floating points. You will find out that the result of `10^20 + 2` is only `10^20` because you have a fixed digit resolution (6-7 digits for float and 15-16 digits for double). When you calculate with numbers that have huge differences in magnitude the smaller ones will just "disappear".

**Question: Why does multiply 1.39 * 10^6 get 139000 but multiplying 1.39 * 10^5 not?**

This could be because of the order of magnitude. 10000 has 5 digits, 1.39 has 3 digits (distance 7 - just within the float). Both could be near enough to "show" the problem. When it comes to 100000 you have 6 digits but you have one more magnitude difference to 1.39 (distance 8 - just out of float). Therefore one of the trailing digits gets cut off and you get a more "natural" result. (This is just one reason for this. Compiler, OS and other reasons might exist)

Comment: but why when I multiply 1.39 * 100 000 I get 139000 but with multipling by 10 000 not.

Comment: This could be because of the order of magnitude. 10000 has 5 digits, 1.39 has 3 digits (distance 7 - just within the float). Both could be near enough to "show" the problem. When it comes to 100000 you have 6 digits but you have one more magnitude difference to 1.39 (distance 8 - just out of float). Therefore one of the trailing digits gets cut off and you get a more "natural" result.

Comment: thanks for answer, maybe you can include this in your original answer.

Comment: One more thing is there any algorithm to check is the number  base two number?

Comment: I altered my response. According to your other question - It's hard to know this in advance when you convert a string into a float (A trivial approach could be to manually do the division [in string format] and output an error if it's not a base 2 but this would be REALLY dirty). I would not rely on ANY solution that might exist. The far more interesting question is your use case. Most likely there is a better solution without the hassle of float point impression.

Comment: my use case is following I have some coefficient which is for adjusting some number  and this is stored as double. So I asked you about check for base two number to add a limitation to not define this number to any value which is not   a base two number.

Comment: When this is a completely mathematical problem, you should think about a fraction representation. `1.39` is equal to `139/100`. This fraction is easily multiplied by `10^5` and then (after the multiplication) solved to a float result. This is also the way most computer algebraic systems use (otherwise you are screwed). If you need to know if your result is "near" the expected result [eg in IF-ELSE situations] you can use an epsilon-delta criterion with respect to the "expected" result.

Comment: 139/100 was also in my mind but it seems for me some dirty fix :)  so I asked here to see maybe there is some nice solution I am not aware. In terms of IF-ELSE situations I know about headache of this with floating point numbers but fortunately in my case I do not have such a case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166847/discussion-between-alex-and-t-m).